# Update Mini Cart After Free Product Add Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, mini-cart

I made a module for free product like if Cart Subtotal is above $600 then a product programmatically add to cart, for this I made an event called `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`, so when I add product in cart it check if Cart Subtotal is greater then $600 then a free product is added to the cart **BUT** the problem is that when I add product, Mini Cart count display it as only 1 item in cart but inside mini cart there are 2 item...

[image: MINICART]

Here is how I'm adding free product:

```
<?php

namespace Hotairtools\RequestPricing\Observer;

class UpdateFreeProduct implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_formKey;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_cart              = $cart;
        $this->_scopeConfig       = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_checkoutSession   = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_formKey           = $formKey;
        $this->_quoteRepository   = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        //$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $enableSetting =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('freesetting/freesetting/enable');
        $freeProductIds =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('freesetting/freesetting/productid', $storeScope);
        $amount =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('freesetting/freesetting/amount', $storeScope);
        // $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData();
        //if($product){
        $cartItems = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $cartProductIds = [];
        foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
            $cartProductIds[] = $cartItem->getProduct()->getId();
        }
        $subTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

        if ($subTotal > $amount && $enableSetting == '1') {
            if (!in_array($freeProductIds, $cartProductIds)) {
                $params = [
                    'form_key' => $this->_formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $freeProductIds,
                    'qty' => 1
                ];
                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($freeProductIds);
                //echo "<pre/>"; print_r($_product->getData()); exit;
                $_product->setPrice(0);
                $this->_cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                $this->_cart->saveQuote();
                $this->_cart->save();
            }

            /* update price */
            $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $itemq) {
                if ($itemq->getProduct()->getId() == $freeProductIds) {
                        $itemq->setQty(0);
                        $itemq->setCustomPrice(0);
                        $itemq->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
                        $itemq->setRowTotal(0);
                        $itemq->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        $itemq->save();
                }
            }
            $quote->save();
        /* updtae price over */
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to replace $itemq->setQty(0);  by  $itemq->setQty(1); ?

Comment: Yes I did but no result :(